# Google translate - translate back to default language / reset translation

Tags: javascript, translation, google-translate

I am using the Google translate dropdown on my websites and noticed that when the site is translated and than set back to the default language the words are again translated instead of the script unloading / resetting translation. This makes some words really weird.

An example is the word 'home' which I think a lot of languages use in the menu for their homepage. The flow will be as following:

1. website is in native language (Dutch) and has 'home' in the menu.
2. website is translated into English and the word 'home' remains 'home'
3. website is translated back into Dutch and the word 'home' becomes 'huis' (meaning house).
4. When refreshing the page everything is as it should be again

Is there a way to reset the translation once you translate back without having to reload the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is set when translation is triggered. The cookie (googtrans) Can be unset by letting it expire on a past date. But even than you still need to reload the page to see it, probably the api does something like this already. So I thought of a solution where you reload the page with javascript when the native language is selected.

It can be done by adding this piece of jQuery

```
jQuery(document).on("change","#google_language_translator select",function() {
    if(jQuery(this).val() == 'nl'){ //value needs to be equal to default language, in my case nl
        location.reload(); 
    }
});
```

It feels a bit hacky so please let me know if there is something more clean

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the next JavaScript function:

```
function dismissGoogleTranslate() {

    // find `iframe` element with GoogleTranslate select and buttons
    var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-banner-frame')[0] 
              || document.getElementById(':1.container');
    if (!iframe) return;

    // search all buttons from the retrieved iframe
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var restore_el = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("button");

    // fire `click` event on the `restore` button, that `Shows the origin`
    for (var i = 0; i < restore_el.length; i++) {
        if (restore_el[i].id.indexOf("restore") >= 0) {
            restore_el[i].click();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```